# Conditional validations are not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

I am using data annotations for client side validations. I have two scenarios where I am using `[Required]` and `[RequiredIfTrue]`. Issue is my conditional validations are not working.

**Working:**

Model:

```
[DisplayName(@"Custom Email Confirmation Address")]
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = @"Invalid Email Address")]
public string CustomEmailConfirmationAddress { get; set; }
```

View:

```
<div>
    <%=Html.RequiredLabelFor(m => m.CustomEmailConfirmationAddress) %>
    <%=Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CustomEmailConfirmationAddress, new { maxlength = 100 })%>
    <%=Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CustomEmailConfirmationAddress)%>
</div>
```

**NOT Working:**

Scenario = If `ShowConceptOptInMessage` is checked than make `ConceptEmailOptInMessage` and `PrivacyPolicy` field required.

Model:

```
[DisplayName("Show Concept Opt-In Message")]
public bool ShowConceptOptInMessage { get; set; }

[RequiredIfTrue("ShowConceptOptInMessage", ErrorMessage = "Concept Email Opt-In Message is required")]
[DisplayName("Concept Email Opt-In Message")]
public string ConceptEmailOptInMessage { get; set; }

[RequiredIfTrue("ShowConceptOptInMessage", ErrorMessage = "Concept Privacy Policy is required")]
[DisplayName("Concept Privacy Policy")]
public string PrivacyPolicy { get; set; }
```

View:

```
<div>
    <%=Html.LabelFor(m => m.ShowConceptOptInMessage) %>
    <%=Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ShowConceptOptInMessage)%>
    <%=Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ShowConceptOptInMessage)%>
</div>

 <div>
    <%=Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConceptEmailOptInMessage) %>
    <%=Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.ConceptEmailOptInMessage, new { maxlength = 1000 })%>
    <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ConceptEmailOptInMessage)%>
</div>

<div>
    <%=Html.LabelFor(m => m.PrivacyPolicy) %>
    <%=Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.PrivacyPolicy)%>
    <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PrivacyPolicy)%>
</div>
```

Controller method for both scenario:

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ConceptConfigurationModel model)
{
    try
    {
        if (this.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // model
            this.ConceptManager.SaveConcept(model);
            model.Submitted = true;
        }
    }
    catch (BusinessLogicException ex)
    {
        this.ModelState.AddModelError("ConceptName", ex.Message);
    }
    ModelState.Clear();
    this.ConceptManager.FillConceptModel(model);

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you have accepted an answer which has nothing to do with your problem and is just an awful hack. Assuming your using the [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIfTrue]` and you have included the relevant scripts, then your code works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ASP.NET MVC 4, RequiredIf is not working, I have achieved the same using jquery unobtrusive , add the below javascript method

```
function AddValidation()
{
var showConceptOptInMessage = $("#ShowConceptOptInMessage").val();
  if(showConceptOptInMessage)
{
  $("#ConceptEmailOptInMessage").attr('data-val-required', 'Concept Email Opt-In Message is required');
  $("#PrivacyPolicy ").attr('data-val-required', 'Concept Privacy Policy is required');
 }
   $('form').removeData('validator');
    $('form').removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('form');
}
```

Comment: I added this and `showConceptOptInMessage` value is coming as `undefined`. What am I missing here? How to call this function or what to pass as container if I do something like this  '<%=Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.SnapfingerOptInDefaultToChecked, new { onclick="AddValidation()"} )%>` . Or is there any other way to call this function on check box click event?

Comment: I've edited the answer removed the container as you don't have the div that is the main div name, directly call the  dom elements within the method, i.e. AddValidation() { $("#ShowConceptOptInMessage").val()}

Comment: I figured that out but issue is, once I check the field it is working but when I unchecked it, this validations should be removed which is not happening. I tried ` $( " #ConceptEmailOptInMessage").attr('data-val-required', 'Concept Email Opt-In Message is required', true);` & ` $( " #ConceptEmailOptInMessage").attr('data-val-required', 'Concept Email Opt-In Message is required', false);` which is not working

Comment: everytime you call addvalidation method, if the checkbox is checked, add the validation, if unchecked remove the attr i.e. $( " #ConceptEmailOptInMessage").removeAttr('data-val-required') something like that;and call  this again $('form').removeData('validator');
    $('form').removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('form');

Comment: Minor change, `$( "#ShowConceptOptInMessage").val();` always gives me true whether its checked or unchecked so I used `$('#ShowConceptOptInMessage').is(':checked')` which gives me true...false based on checked...unchecked. Thank you